The construction "Что за это случилось"
In Поздний ответ by Anna Akhmatova we have:

Полюбуйтесь, родимые пашни,
Что за это случилось со мной.

It is unclear to me.
My guess is that мной after Полюбуйтесь is implicit ("admire me"), but I don't understand the construction of the second verse. Is this construction similar to the one of the following sentence?

я не спросил, что за родственник он ей

(Матренин двор by Aleksandr Solzhenitsyn). In that case родственник is at the nominative - is it the same for это? But while I understand the latter sentence ("I didn't ask what his relationship was to her") because спросить, что за + substantive at the nominative makes sense to me, I don't understand полюбоваться (+ instrumental), что за + это.

This is not idiomatic Russian.
The phrase literally means "look what happened to me for this", or, better, "look what happened to me because of this", or, still better, "look how it served me".
За это, in this context, means what it says on the tin: "for this", as in меня за это наградили "I've been rewarded for this" or меня за это наказали "I've been punished for this".
This preposition assumes a sentient agent, so, poetic license aside, за это случилось is a poor choice of words, and из-за этого would be a more natural option.

Из-за, yes. That is right here. In other contexts, за can mean "about" -  говорить за что = о чём - which is Odessa colloquial Russian.

Thank you very much! I realized that I was completely wrong and my mistake comes from the fact I misunderstood Полюбуйтесь: on gramota.ru I read now "Полюбуйся; полюбуйтесь, в зн. межд. Неодобр. Взгляни(те), как нехорошо, безобразно, возмутительно." but this meaning is not given by Викисловарь, thus I didn't expect that after "полюбоваться" "что" could introduce a completive.
